# se cambia texto de un button despues obtener el focus

Tags: android, android-studio, botón

He estado teniendo un problema:

Cuando escribo en el `EditText`, luego le doy `Enter` del teclado, pasa el `focus` hacia el `Button`, pero cuando escribo, este se va agrega en el `text` del `Button`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Viendo afectado el Texto que posee el `Button`, aquí se podría ocultar, pero el problema es cuando un lector de código de barras se conecta al dispositivo, entonces lo que escanea el lector de barras se vuelve a ir hacia el `Button`

he intentado cambiar el `focus` del `Button` hacia el `EditText` pero sigue sin funcionar

```
txtParametro.requestFocus();
```

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBusca"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
        android:onClick="loadProductos"
        android:text="Buscar"
        />
```

muchas gracias por tu lectura y ayuda

Comment: El problema es en cómo estas asignando el texto, puede ser que estés haciendo una referencia equívoca. Puedes agregar el código para ver que procedimiento estás haciendo para asignar las referencias de las vistas y el texto?

Comment: esta bien @Andrespengineer, ahorita lo agrego, muchas gracias

Comment: @GrsnChml que realiza el método loadProductos() ?

Comment: busca en sqlite, en la tabla **productos**, todos los que coincidan con esos parametros ingresados, luego de eso los guarda en `ArrayList<Produto>` y despues se ingresa en un adapter, y por ultimo ese adapter se inserta en el listView  `listViewProductos.setAdapter(productoAdapter);`